# Precision of a class turns out to be zero using MLP classifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a data set of about `45000` samples each with binary output of either `0` or `1`. But after using the MLP classifier in sklearn package, I obtained a model that always has an output of `1` no matter what the input is. The precision of class `0` is zero. I have tried changing the hyperparameters of the model but the output is the same. Can anyone suggest a way to get over it?

```
     precision    recall  f1-score   support                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
0       0.00      0.00      0.00     19967                                                                                                                              
1       0.57      1.00      0.73     26688                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
avg / total       0.33      0.57      0.42     46655
```

PS: My code

```
    loc = './new_attributes_66.csv'
data = pd.read_csv(loc)

scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range = (-1,1))
scaler.fit(data)
data = scaler.transform(data)
print data


input = data[:,0:64]
output = data[:,65]
X_tr, X_tst, y_tr, y_tst = train_test_split(input, output, test_size=0.1)

clf = MLPClassifier(solver='sgd', alpha=1e-5, hidden_layer_sizes=(40,121), random_state=0, warm_start = True, tol = 0.0000001, early_stopping = False, learning_rate='adaptive',learning_rate_init = 0.1, max_iter=10000,shuffle=True,verbose=True)

clf.fit(X_tr,y_tr)
predicted = clf.predict(input)
#print "Accuracy using MLP classifier: "
print metrics.precision_score(output, predicted)
#print confusion_matrix(y_tst,predicted)
print metrics.classification_report(output,predicted)
#print clf.coefs_
```

Link to the dataset (csv) : https://app.box.com/s/vfqgool2u9ovdc9oyi9elq99aor6c6gk

Update:
I have modified my code and results according to the latest results. I could improve the precision and recall as:

```
         precision    recall  f1-score   support

   -1.0       0.53      0.10      0.17     19967
    1.0       0.58      0.93      0.72     26688

avg / total       0.56      0.58      0.48     46655
```

With an accuracy of `58.14 %`. In what other ways can the hyperparametrs be varied?

Comment: what does your data look like?

Comment: @gionni my data has `66` attributes and target output of either `0` or `1`.

Comment: what are these 66 attributes like? are they continuous, categorical, mixed? Are you using preprocessing?

Comment: What are number of rows with label `0` ?

Comment: The 66 attributes are continious.....and I didn't count the rows, but since the recall of `1` is `1.00` and `0` is `0.00`, I think `57%` of the data is `1` and rest is `0`

Comment: are all the attributes the same order of magnitude? If some are in [0,1] and others are in [-inf, +inf] , that might cause a problem. Jst asking to make sure the input data is suitable for the MLP

Comment: @yobro97 it doesn't work that way. Either provide a link to the dataset or post the exact count of labels.

Comment: @MohammedKashif The number of `1` s in my dataset is `26688`. Total size is `46656`.

Comment: @gionni can you please add the code for reference

Comment: @gionni all values are scaled out of `100`

Comment: @yobro97 is it possible to post a link to your dataset to get a more hands on the problem ?

Comment: @MohammedKashif added the link to dataset :)

Answer (score 3):

Your data may be suffering from class imbalance problem. It might be the case that the number of sample with label `1` far outnumber those with label `0`. There are various ways to tackle class imbalance problem :

- [Combating Imbalanced classes in machine Learning](https://machinelearningmastery.com/tactics-to-combat-imbalanced-classes-in-your-machine-learning-dataset/)
- [Perform under sample and over sampling to tackle class imbalance](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/imbalanced-learn)
- [Stratified split - Sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedShuffleSplit.html)
- [SMOTE](http://www.chioka.in/class-imbalance-problem/)

You can also try checking out different values of alpha or different shapes of hidden layers. Maybe the current configuration that you are using is not able to learn properly.

Comment: I have added my dataset and I don' think I face this problem.

Comment: @yobro97 I tried experimenting with your dataset but couldn't get the recall for class `0` to go higher than 0.0. However, I the precision value for both classes became positive. I will let you know if I find someway to improve the recall for class `0`

Comment: How did you get the precision to increase?

Comment: I experimented a little too, I got a recall of 0.20 for class 0, the real problem in my opinion is that it is hard to increase the accuracy. The baseline accuracy, that is the accuracy you get by predicting the most frequent value (1 in your case) is around 57%. Now, with MLP the best accuracy I got, after normalizing the input data is... around 57%, hence there is no significant improvement. Out of curiosity I also fit an adaboost (`sklearn.ensamble.AdaBoostClassifier`), and, without optimizing the hyperparameters, got an accuracy of 58%. I guess your data is not easily predictable...

Comment: I tried scaling all the data to `-1,1` by using the `MinMaxScaler` from the `sklearn.preprocessing` library. I improved the results as updated above. Can you suggest some hyper parameter modifications I can try?

Comment: Hey I wrote an answer giving the present best results. Can you suggest any other classifiers based on your observations of the data behavior for further improvement.

Answer (score 2):

Hey guys after a suggestion from Mohammed Kasif, I tried the `AdaBoostClassifier` on the data and scaled the data to `-1,1` and obtained the following results:

Accuracy: `0.682432189042`

```
         precision    recall  f1-score   support

   -1.0       0.59      0.56      0.57     19967
    1.0       0.68      0.71      0.70     26688

avg / total       0.64      0.65      0.64     46655
```

This is a large improvement compared to `57-58 %` we were able to get on the `MLPclassifier` or even the `AdaBoostclassifier` without the scaling. Anyone with better results are free to post their ideas :)

Comment: That's not bad at all. If I find time I will try something to get better predictions. Can you post the code that gets a 68% accuracy? If i may suggest, as a next step, if you have done all the parameter selection properly, I would look a bit into variable selection, that might help.